# Performance impact of observable classes

Tags: java, android, observable

I am currently working on an App in Android. For all my `Models` I use the same `Base` class. Now I need some of the child `Models` be `Observable` classes. The easiest way to implement this for me at this point is just to make the `Base` class extend `Observable`. I did this and everything works just great.

I wonder if this will have any **performance impact** for the system. Note that this has to run on older devices also.

Another option which I have is to create a new `Base` that would looks similar as the `Base` I have at this moment, only difference would be that one would extend `Observable` and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My my. You should only worry about performance if you encounter performance issues. Or, if you are really interested in understanding performance ... then you have to dive into the whole subject. The worst thing you can do: come up with **naive** assumptions how this or that potentially would influence performance.

In other words: the fact that all your classes extend Observable does by itself not cause "performance problems". But: this very much indicates that you might have **design problems**.

You don't use inheritance for *convenience* (aka code reuse). You use inheritance in order to define an abstraction, a model of reality. Something that allows you to change things over time; whilst at the same time protecting you from changing existing behavior inadvertently.

In other words: don't focus on the absolutely irrelevant "performance" aspect of Base extending Observerable. You should be much more focused on coming up with proper, sound OO designs; driven from [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principles for example.

Comment: Yes, I agree that in terms of design this is a horrible approach. I overlooked this aspect.